# Eclipse Checkbox "Errors in Workspace" Reset

Tags: eclipse, reset

I accidentally checkt the Checkbox when Errors are in Code.
This is the Message:

Errors in Workspace
Errors exist in required project(s):
*project name*
Proceed with launch?
[] Always launch without asking
Proceed Cancel

[Picture of the Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajFwm.png)

How can i reset this Checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution in the eclipse settings:

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4rJA.png)